# delete_model() error when cleaning up AWS sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, resource-cleanup

I followed the tutorial on https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/

I got an error when trying to clean up with the following code.

```
xgb_predictor.delete_endpoint()
xgb_predictor.delete_model()
```

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeEndpointConfig operation: Could not find the endpoint configuration.

Does it mean I need to delete the model first instead?

I checked on the console and deleted the model manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to delete the model prior to deleting the endpoint. From the error logs looks like its not able to find the endpoint configuration. Can you verify if you are setting delete_endpoint_config to True

```
xgb_predictor.delete_endpoint(delete_endpoint_config=True)
```

Additionally, you can verify if the endpoint_config is still avaiable on the AWS console.